# Converting macros to enum types in C

Tags: c, enums, macros

I am little bit confused. In our production environment, there are few macros already defined. These macros used to return some value. Now our requirement is to prepare some lookup based on these Macros' value. I have created char* array and defined some string at appropriate index. But my manger asked me to convert these macros to enum types and then do lookup. How to implement this using enum? What is the advantage of that? These macros are being used in many different files. Do I have to change anything if I defined enum type? 
Thanks in advance !

Sample code:

```
#define macro_1 1
#define macro_2 2
#define macro_3 3
#define macro_4 4
```

Lookup:

```
const char* lookup[] = {.....};
```

Comment: One direct advantage is that using an array requires sequentially-increasing macro values (i.e 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). When using an enum, the values can be arbitrary integers.

Comment: @Rushy Panchal: Thanks for prompt help. Can you please show me an example? Is it possible to do lookup using enum types? How can I define string in enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How to implement this using enum?
   I suppose your manager asked you to map the macros to enum type. You can simply define an enum type, as long the macros all have integer value, and the enum values don't use the same names as macros.
2. What is the advantage of that?
   Macros are generally not encouraged as they are replaced by value before entering the compiler, it can be error prone compared to using enum types that are checked and managed by compiler.
3. These macros are being used in many different files. Do I have to change anything if I defined enum type?
   Unfortunately yes. But if your macros are isolated in a centeral header file, you can work around by renaming the macros and naming the original names to enum value.

You may find this article useful.  http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/enumerated_types.html

Some codes

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define old_macro_1 1
#define old_macro_2 2
#define old_macro_3 3

enum MacroValues {
  macro_1 = old_macro_1,
  macro_2 = old_macro_2,
  macro_3 = old_macro_3
};

void test_macros(void)
{
  const char* lookup[] = {"M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"};
  // use an enum variable directly
  printf("enum MacrosValues %d\n", macro_1);
  // define an enum variable to use as index
  enum MacroValues m1 = macro_2;
  printf("lookup[%d] = %s\n", m1, lookup[m1]);
}

int main(void)
{
  test_macros();
  return 0;
}
```